# Portal fiction fantasy series where the male protagonist has sex with Mother Earth and changes elves to Keebler elf size

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai

What is the name of the fantasy series that is portal fiction that has a male protagonist who has sex with Mother Earth and changes the elves from 7 feet tall to Keebler elf size (less than 40cm). I believe it was written in the 90s.

Comment: Ah, yes, I could not have guessed that it was an isekai. Also, is there supposed to be a cause and effect relation here?

Comment: What is _portal fiction_?

Comment: It's where they are transported to a different world

Comment: A friend told me once 'Nothing good ever comes out of a portal."